# Young adult fantasy/scifi novel about Ancient Egypt

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to remember a book I read about 10-12 years ago. This is a young adult fantasy/scifi book, very similar to [Kuromori series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/171877-sword-of-kuromori), but about Ancient Egypt. I believe it was originally written in English, but I read it in Russian.

What I remember:

- the setting is modern (at least, there were modern airplanes, but not sure about mobile phones)
- the main hero is a boy about 14-15 years old who lives alone
- his father is an engineer working in Egypt, probably on Suez Canal
- somehow, strange things start happening with the boy, and they are related with Ancient Egypt gods/monsters/visions
- shortly, a man who calls himself Ptah (like an Egyptian god) arrives to this boy and tells that he's a friend of his father's
- boy finds him suspicious
- still, the man possesses some kind of superpowers, partly related with pure magic, partly - with rituals
- they start a long travel which finishes in Egypt
- they are accompanied by Anubis (who comes as a doberman dog) and Bast
  (who comes as a cat)
- there is some reason why they travel and what are they trying to accomplish, all that I remember that it was related with Akhenaten and the god Seth
- they find the Eye of Horus on the way that plays a significant part in the plot
- they fight with some gods or monsters, the boy doesn't have any superpowers but somehow they cope with it
- everything ends well - the boy and his father are reunited in Egypt

Answer (score 2):

[The Red Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Pyramid_(novel)) has many of these elements, although not all.  (The heroes are brother and sister, Anubis appears as a handsome boy, not a doberman...).

[image: Book cover]

> The novel opens with Carter and their father Julius Kane to visit Sadie, who has been living with her maternal grandparents since the death of the siblings' mother, Ruby Kane. Julius, who is secretly a magician but posing as a simple egyptologist, takes the siblings to the British Museum, where he tries to bring Osiris (the Egyptian god of the Underworld) back into the mortal world. Julius's magic has the unintended side effect of also summoning the gods Horus, Isis, Nephthys, and Set; and alerting the magicians Zia Rashid and Michel Desjardins to his actions, which are illegal within the magical community. Set, a god of chaos, captures Julius and destroys the museum. Unbeknownst to Carter and Sadie, each of the gods chooses a mortal host from the humans in the room.
>
> Carter and Sadie are taken to Brooklyn by their uncle Amos, who explains to them that they are descended from a long line of magicians, beginning with the Egyptian pharaohs Ramesses the Great and Narmer. He also explains the grave danger Set poses to the world, and goes to find the loose god. While he is away, the mansion is attacked by minions of Set. With help from Sadie's cat Muffin, who is host to the goddess Bast, and Zia Rashid, they escape to Cairo. Once there, Carter and Sadie discover that they are hosts to the gods Horus and Isis, respectively. They train in magic until the magicians' leader Iskandar dies and Michel Desjardins orders their deaths for illegally collaborating with gods. The siblings escape and formulate a plan to defeat Set - hoping to both rescue their father and clear their names within the magical community.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately no. I've read The Red Pyramid also, much later (like half a year ago probably) and I'm sure it's not the one =( In the book that I'm looking for, the boy was the only child (so no sister).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the novel *Die Prophezeiung* (*The Prophecy*) by German fantasy author Wolfgang Hohlbein. Unfortunately I could only find a German Wikipedia article.
[Die Prophezeiung (Hohlbein)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Prophezeiung_(Hohlbein)).

The boy's name is Aton (from Echnaton). His parents are Egypt enthusiasts. His father works on a dam project in Egypt and his father's friend is a man named Petach (later revealed to be the ancient Egypt god Ptah). His parents get a doberman called Anubis and there is also a grey cat called Bastet.